# how to make my column names in one line in the pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a general question related to pandas dataframe:

1. when I read my file, I found that my column's name is in two lines instead of one line, which makes me can't get the all column names. How to adjust it to make it all in one line?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqPaP.jpg)
2. if I want to assign all my column names to a variable named "columns", is this correct?
   columns = data.columns
   columns

Comment: Use `data.reset_index()`

Comment: **1**. `shopid` is the `index` of your dataframe so to make it column use `data=data.reset_index()`.... **2** use `columns = data.columns.to_list()` between you can also use `columns = data.columns`